# Preserving types on the back-end

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, types

In order to preserve types during CRUD Ajax requests I want to json encode on the front-end and decode on the back-end.  Is this worth doing?  Is there going to be a noticeable difference in computing speed/memory between casting particular params as ints and blindly decoding requests with json headers?

Pros:
Easier to code back-end commands.
Much easier to scale.

Cons:
Possible speed/memory overhead.

Background:
ExtJS front-end, Django back-end.  One developer, single website with the hope of multiple developers and websites. :)  As of right now I don't plan on having that many CRUD commands where the types are important, but I can see later down the road that there may be a lot of commands that need particular types.  Implementing the encoding/decoding functionality should be relatively simple, I'm just worrying that I may be suffering performance for maintainability.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: Cast them on the back end if you need to, the front end (if it's javascript) probaby doesn't know or care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding/decoding JSON in Django is not going to be an issue performance-wise, although I'd point out that [`simplejson`](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson) is a bit more performant than the `json` module in Python 2.6/2.7, so you might want to use that.